# MVC View Throwing Error From Code That Is Not There

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I have a razor partial view, which is throwing and error which says:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

When I look at the stack trace, I find a call to `String.Format(string, args)`.

The problem is in this line of code there is no such call to `String.Format()`.  Furthermore, the debugger highlights a section of code where there is no such call to `String.Format()`.

I have tried deleting temporary internet files.  I have tried cleaning and rebuilding.  I am using Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2013 Update 4.

Here is a photo of the debugger at the time of error throwing (note the green highlight, and also the red highlight from the break point - seems to be selecting something else that isn't there):

[image]

Comment: The debugger can't always show you exactly where the problem is in the source, typically you have to look either before or after the place that the debugger claims.. and in your case, it's after... Stephen's answer is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the following lines that are throwing an exception (4 in total)

```
@string.Format("1_{1}", i)
```

should be

```
@string.Format("1_{0}", i)
```

You're only providing one parameter to `string.Format()`, which corresponds to index 0 of the internal params array. Consider the following code:

```
    public static string Format(string format, params object[] args);
```

This is the BCL signature for string.Format(), notice how the 'args' parameter is declared as an array. the `params` keyword merely allows syntactic sugar which hides the array from consumer code. The [`format items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format.aspx#FormatItem) in the `format string` represent a 0-based index into that array.

References

- ['Format Item' on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format.aspx#FormatItem)

Comment: you got that out of his picture ? nice!

Comment: Yeah it's a bit small probably.  Thanks Stephen.  I feel a bit foolish, but that debugger behavior threw me right off!

Comment: you may also find the following shorthand more readable, and less error prone `@("1_" + i)` (instead of the `@string.Format()` method you've got above.)

Comment: That definitely is more readable and less error prone - thank you for this.